# Keeping the format of text (its paragraphs) echoed from mySQL and also apply CSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am retrieving a text from mySQL database table column which is in three separate paragraphs in the database. To preserve the format I use the pre tag:

```
<h3 class="Container1">
        <pre>
             <?php
                  $result = $conn->query($sql);
                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo $row["Explanation"];
                                    }
                            }
            ?>
</pre>
```

Now I have also defined in my CSS file Container1, which has a defined font-family and so-forth.

Now the result I am getting is preserved text with the correct paragraphs as from the database but Container1 CSS is no longer applied. Is there anyway I can have the Container1 CSS also applied?

Thanks

Comment: yes in your css style add `!important`. like this: `margin-top:10px !important;`

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal I did so, but its the format is the same as that of the mySQL database

Comment: Found a fix using the 'nl2br' function to echo